# Cache System Supporting Java Integration

Tags: java, caching, memcached, ehcache

Am building a restful web service which needs to populate data (from a parsed JSON object) into a cache.

Question(s):

1. What are the cheapest (preferably open source) and easiest to use cache systems that support Java, Web Service (Restful), and tomcat integration?
2. Do they have an expiration policy?
3. Do they have support for in-memory and / or file system persistence?

I am seeking something that doesn't require a big learning curve.

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll put [Guava Caching solution](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) on the table which:

1. Is lighter than Memcached and EHCache
2. Has size/time/ref [eviction policies](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Eviction)
3. Lives solely in memory. If you are after built-in persisting capabilities the creators themselves point you to other solutions like Memcached in [this section](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Applicability).

On top of that I'll add my personal experience that is easy to use and intuitive through the use of the builder design pattern as you'll find out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use memcached, it supports all the three requirement you have listed. Memcached use in-memory cache. It's open source and very easy to learn.